# "top" property with same value is different in showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some social icons and I put a div that its visibility is hidden and I want to show it when every of the icons is hovered. I wrote the jQuery code below and works nicely, I have used `console.log` to see `event.pageY` and `top` property when is visible and they are same :

```
$(function() {
  $('.social-icons a img').hover(function(event) {
    var socialIconName = $(this).data('name');
    var Y = event.clientY;
    var DOMTarget = $('#social-icon-text');

    DOMTarget.text(socialIconName);
    DOMTarget.css({
      'top': Y,
      'visibility': 'visible'
    });

  }, function(event) {
    $('#social-icon-text').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

My HTML code :

```
<div class="social-icons">
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/GitHub.png" alt="GitHub" data-name="GitHub"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram" data-name="Instagram"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/Telegram.png" alt="Telegram" data-name="Telegram"></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="Images/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter" data-name="Twitter"></a>
    
    <div id="social-icon-text">Instagram</div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS :

```
#social-icon-text {
  background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #D4FC79 0%, #96E6A1 100%);
  color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 0;
  left: 120%;
  text-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  visibility: hidden;
}

#social-icon-text::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid #D4FC79;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[My problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkQfp.png)

My problem is when the `div` is appeared, although `pageY` and `top` property are the same but `div` has higher value that is showed underneath of the icon but I want them beside together.
Any response will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] as a snippet then we can test?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I edited and put an image, if you need it online tell me again please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `position` method and its `top` property instead of changing `pageX` value.